# Swift -Get Remainder by itself to Nearest Tenth from Double

Tags: ios, swift, double, fractions

I have a video and I need to get the seconds and milliseconds separated and the milliseconds rounded down to the nearest tenth. If the video duration starts off at **4.333333333333333** secs I use `floor(num * 10) / 10` to get it to **4.3**. When I try to get the remainder by itself using `.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1)` and/or `modf(num).1` I keep getting **0.2999999999999998** instead of **0.3**. Why is this happening?

```
let mixCompositionDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(mixComposition.duration)
print("mixCompositionDuration: ", mixCompositionDuration) // 4.333333333333333
            
let dubl = Double(mixCompositionDuration)
print("dubl: ", dubl) // 4.333333333333333
            
let mixCompositionRoundDown = floor(dubl * 10) / 10
print("mixCompositionRoundDown: ", mixCompositionRoundDown)  // 4.3

let remainder = mixCompositionRoundDown.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1)
print("remainder: ", remainder) // 0.2999999999999998

let mod = modf(mixCompositionRoundDown)
print("mod: ", mod) // (4.0, 0.2999999999999998)

let modRemainder = mod.1
print("modRemainder: ", modRemainder) // 0.2999999999999998
```

Comment: Are you trying to display the seconds and milliseconds as a string to the user?

Comment: no, l have a timer and I need to use the exact milliseconds to set the timer. For example if the video is 4.3 seconds I need the timer to max out at 4.3 seconds when it starts counting. I set the seconds a **4** but I need to set the milliseconds at **3** or whatever that remainder value is.

Comment: Then 0.2999999999999998 should work. See [is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Ok, I'm reading it now. My way to set the milliseconds was `milliseconds = Int(remainder * 10)`, the problem was I kept getting 2 instead of 3

Comment: It seems like you should `round` it before converting to `Int`. By the way, 4.3 seconds is 4 seconds and _300_ milliseconds.

Comment: thanks! using `round` before converting it to an `Int` fixed my issue